# Maven packaging fail Lucene, SPI does not exist Exception

Tags: java, maven, lucene, spi

I built a Java application for indexing. I am using Apache Lucene 5.3.1.
When I run the application in IDE (IntelJ IDEA 2016.1.1 Community Edition), it runs normally. When I try to run the application from jar file I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Cannot instantiate SPI class: org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene53.Lucene53Codec
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:77)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder.<clinit>(Codec.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.getDefault(Codec.java:140)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:120)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:140)
   .
   .
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat with name 'Lucene50' does not exist.      You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting
this SPI to your classpath.  The current classpath supports the following names: [IDVersion]
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.lookup(NamedSPILoader.java:109)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat.forName(PostingsFormat.java:112)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene53.Lucene53Codec.<init>(Lucene53Codec.java:160)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene53.Lucene53Codec.<init>(Lucene53Codec.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:67)
    ... 13 more
```

There is a similar issue [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/190786) , but the solution with maven-shade-plugin didn't help.
Here is pom.xml related segments.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-codecs</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    ...
    <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharFilterFactory</resource>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory</resource>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenizerFactory</resource>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec</resource>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat</resource>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat</resource>
        </transformer>
</transformers>
```

The problem is that for some reason it tries to load something from Lucene50.

Any help is valuable!

Comment: hi I just wonder if you solved this problem as I got the same issue

Comment: I am too facing this issue - any solution?

Answer (score 4):

So that's my solution of that problem (Maven)

```
`<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>mainClassName</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
`
```

Files org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec, org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat, org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat include information about codecs used in the project. They should be put in META-INF/services directory (should be created if not exists). In my case problem was in several postingFormats, Codecs and DocValuesFormats, I added them into the files and the problem was solved.

**Example of org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec file:**

```
org.apache.lucene.codecs.simpletext.SimpleTextCodec
org.apache.lucene.codecs.appending.AppendingCodec
org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40Codec
org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene410.Lucene410Codec
org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene41.Lucene41Codec
```

**Example of org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat file:**

```
org.apache.lucene.codecs.memory.MemoryDocValuesFormat
org.apache.lucene.codecs.memory.DirectDocValuesFormat
org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene410.Lucene410DocValuesFormat
```

**Example of org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat file:**

```
org.apache.lucene.codecs.bloom.BloomFilteringPostingsFormat
org.apache.lucene.codecs.memory.DirectPostingsFormat
org.apache.lucene.codecs.memory.FSTOrdPostingsFormat
org.apache.lucene.codecs.memory.FSTPostingsFormat
org.apache.lucene.codecs.memory.MemoryPostingsFormat
org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40PostingsFormat
org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene41.Lucene41PostingsFormat
```

In your case you should do the same for Lucene50.